# Javascript: Sending callback function to class constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, oop, callback

There's probably a really simple solution to this, but I'm looking for a way to **send a callback function to the constructor of a class and use that callback function to update state in the original class** (in react-native btw).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
export class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bluetooth: {
        isConnected: "false",
        preventAutoReconnect: false,
        connected: {
          id: "",
          name: "none",
          obj: {}
        }
      }
    };
    this.b = new Bluetooth(this.updateBleContext);
  }

  updateBleContext = bleInfo => {
    console.log("updating context");
    this.setState({
      bluetooth: bleInfo
    });
  };
}
```

Trying to use like this:

```
export default class B {
  constructor(updateContext) {
    this.bluetooth = {
      isConnected: "false",
      preventAutoReconnect: false,
      connected: {
        id: "",
        name: "none",
        obj: {}
      }
    };
    this.updateContext = updateContext();
  }

  setDisconnected = () => {
    let bluetooth = this.bluetooth;
    bluetooth.connected.name = "";
    bluetooth.connected.obj = {};
    bluetooth.isConnected = "false";

    this.updateContext(bluetooth);
    this.bluetooth = bluetooth;
  };
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is classB rendered from classA?  If so, just pass updateBleContext in classA’s render. <ClassA updateaBleContext={this.updateaBleContext} />

Comment: it's not used as a component, I don't actually import react in class B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly passing the function into the `B` class.

Inside the `B` class constructor you have :

`this.updateContext = updateContext();`

This assigns `this.updateContext` to the return value of the function call `updateContext();`, which in this case would be `undefined`.

If you want to instead store the function inside the `B` class you would do :

`this.updateContext = updateContext;`

Then you would have access to the function and be able to call it how you would expect :
`this.updateContext(bluetooth);`

```
export default class B {
  constructor(updateContext) {
    this.bluetooth = {
      isConnected: "false",
      preventAutoReconnect: false,
      connected: {
        id: "",
        name: "none",
        obj: {}
      }
    };
    this.updateContext = updateContext;
  }

  setDisconnected = () => {
    let bluetooth = this.bluetooth;
    bluetooth.connected.name = "";
    bluetooth.connected.obj = {};
    bluetooth.isConnected = "false";

    this.updateContext(bluetooth);
    this.bluetooth = bluetooth;
  };
}
```